# Question about deserializing some numbers (bug??)

Tags: python, numpy, pickle

In order to deserialize bytes object, we use pickle.loads()

```
import pickle
import numpy as np
pickle.loads(np.float64(0.34103))
```

and the expected result is like below (because np.float64(0.34103) is not bytes objects, appropriate errors are expected)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnpicklingError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-5c07606a60f1> in <module>
----> 1 pickle.loads(np.float64(0.34103))

UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\xc1'.
```

Here we have some questions that some numbers (it is rare) like 0.34104 prints the following result without errors.

```
pickle.loads(np.float64(0.34104))
```

```
True
```

This occurs only when the converted bytes start with b'\x88 (for example 0.04263, 0.08526, 0.11651 ...)

```
np.float64(0.34104).tobytes()
```

```
b'\x88.\xa8o\x99\xd3\xd5?'
```

Can anyone answer whether this issue is Python bugs?

Any answer will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Pair `tobytes` with `np.frombuffer`, and `pickle.dumps` with `pickle.loads`.  Your attempted pairing isn't meaningful.

Comment: I don't see `tobytes` in your code examples.

Comment: I mean "np.float64(0.34104).tobytes()" gives us binary expression which starts with b'x88. This number prints True instead of errors. Can anyone explain this phenomenon?

Comment: Why are you trying to `pickle.loads(x)` where `x` is no a pickle bytes string? The protocol has not be designed to receive this kind of random data.

Answer (score 2):

`pickle.loads`'s input isn't quite restricted to be a `bytes` object. Quoting the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.loads),

> Return the reconstituted object hierarchy of the pickled representation *data* of an object. *data* must be a [**bytes-like object**](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-bytes-like-object).

and quoting the "bytes-like object" [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-bytes-like-object),

> An object that supports the [Buffer Protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html#bufferobjects) and can export a C-contiguous buffer.

The buffer protocol is a way for objects to expose their underlying memory buffer to other code, for objects where that makes sense. NumPy arrays support the buffer protocol, allowing other code to operate on the underlying storage of an array instead of going through expensive Python-level indexing operations and wrapper objects. NumPy scalars support the buffer protocol too, to make working with 0-dimensional data as seamless as possible.

---

The error with `pickle.loads(np.float64(0.34103))` isn't because `np.float64(0.34103)` isn't bytes. If you tried to pass in an ordinary `float`, you'd get a TypeError because the type is invalid (`float`s aren't bytes-like), but with `np.float64(0.34103)`, the error you get is because `pickle.loads` tries to read the buffer of `np.float64(0.34103)` and finds that the data in there isn't a valid pickle.

With `np.float64(0.34104)`, the buffer's contents *do* happen to be a valid pickle. By fluke, the bytes just happen to match a NEWTRUE opcode, a STOP opcode, and trailing garbage that gets ignored. NEWTRUE pushes a True on the `pickle` stack, STOP stops pickle execution, and the True gets returned.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Python bug. `pickle.loads` works with any [bytes-like object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-bytes-like-object), and a numpy float is one.
From the on this is just how bytes work: bytes represent raw data without type. That the 8 bytes representing numpy float `0.34104` happen to match some 8 bytes representing Python pickle `True` is a mere coincidence.

For pickle protocol 2 in specific, `b'\x88.\xa8o\x99\xd3\xd5?'` happens to be the opcode for `True`, End-Of-Pickle, and trailing garbage that is ignored.

```py
>>> pickletools.dis(b'\x88.\xa8o\x99\xd3\xd5?')
    0: \x88 NEWTRUE
    1: .    STOP
```

---

The byte pattern of "numpy float `0.34104`" for example also matches the little endian unsigned/signed Python integer `4599815250385579656`, the big endian unsigned Python integer `9812965835362522431`, the big endian signed Python integer `-8633778238347029185`, the latin1 string `'\x88.¨o\x99ÓÕ?'` and many other values.

```py
>>> int.from_bytes(np.float64(0.34103), byteorder='big', signed=False)
13915064561919317311
```

Comment: This is *not* how Python works with bytes in general. There is specific NumPy functionality interacting with `pickle.loads` here. Most objects would never be interpreted this way.

Comment: Your claim is that this happens because "This is how bytes work: bytes are raw data without type.", but Python does not treat `bytes` as "raw data without type", and it will not reinterpret the memory representation of arbitrary objects as bytes.

Comment: If you try to pass most objects to `pickle.loads`, it will raise a TypeError immediately rather than trying to do any sort of byte interpretation at all. Your answer immediately jumps to (wrong) assertions about the pickle protocol and the memory layout of `numpy.float64(0.34104)` without even considering why `pickle.loads` is treating this object as valid input.

Comment: That, and the fact that `pickle.loads` takes bytes-like objects. My interpretation of the question is that the most important point is why `pickle` even accepts objects that aren't instances of `bytes` - the question expresses an expectation that non-`bytes` input should raise an error.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica This wasn't obvious to me, since the first iteration explicitly mentioned using ``tobytes``. I have added an appropriate sentence. Thank you for clarifying your criticism.

Comment: I'm glad we could get that cleared up. (The wrong assertion was the assertion that the bytes match "the 8 bytes representing Python pickle True", as if there is only one pickle that unpickles to `True` and these 8 bytes match that pickle. Your edits have also fixed this problem.)